# React.js - Changing state of owner component by an event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this the correct way to handle the model change event -

a. The  handleModelChange function is being passed as onModelChange prop to SubClass.

b. When the model change event triggers, for the re-render to occur, the handler from the SubComponent changes the state of the MainComponent.

```
var _SomeMixin={
    componentWillMount: function() {
                this.props.options.model.on("MODEL_CHANGED", this.props.onModelChange);
        },
        componentWillUnmount: function() {
                this.props.options.model.off("MODEL_CHANGED", this.props.onModelChange);
        },
    /* more mixin functions */
}

var SubComponent = React.createClass({
            mixins: [_SomeMixin],
            render: function() {                    
                 return (
                    <div>
                    <!-- ... more elements .. >
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });


var MainComponent = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return {MainComponentState: []};
            },
            handleModelChange: function() {
                if (this.isMounted()) {
                    this.setState({MainClassState: this.props.options.model.toJSON()});
                }
            },
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <SubClass options={this.props.options} onModelChange={this.handleModelChange} />
                    );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of possible ways to inform parent component that inner component has been changed. But this approach will lead you to a callbacks hell, that you will have to pass every time.

Better solution is to use some state management library like [Moreartyjs](https://github.com/moreartyjs/moreartyjs)